# How to set the path of selenium driver while deploying on server (Godady)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Here i have used this code in c#  selenium 4.12.4

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
var driver = new ChromeDriver( chromeOptions);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/maps/@31.4321498,74.2766182,15z?entry=ttu");
```

but i'm getting the error when i deployed it to server
**Unable to obtain chrome using Selenium Manager;**

Comment: You are not providing enough information for people to help you. What version of Selenium are you trying to deploy? Also post a properly formatted code example as per guidelines please.

Answer (score 0):

Using the documentation, we can see the process the *Automated driver management* process follows:

> 1. **Browser version discovery**. Selenium Manager discovers the browser
>    version (e.g., Chrome, Firefox, Edge) installed in the machine that
>    executes Selenium. This step uses shell commands (e.g.,
>    google-chrome --version).
> 2. **Driver version discovery**. ***With the discovered browser version***, the
>    proper driver version is resolved. For this step, the online
>    metadata/endpoints maintained by the browser vendors (e.g.,
>    chromedriver, geckodriver, or msedgedriver) are used.
> 3. Driver download. The driver URL is obtained with the resolved driver
>    version; with that URL, the driver artifact is downloaded,
>    uncompressed, and stored locally.

[Link](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/#automated-driver-management)

First it tries to discover the version of the required browser (in your case Google Chrome) that is installed and then it tries to download the correct web driver based on and compatible with the discovered Browser version. **Is Chrome installed on this remote server?**

Selenium **cannot install Chrome browser for you**, it can only download the relevant web driver for a given browser.